# SMS url not working with file operation

Tags: php, codeigniter

My question is, i'm using - `$url = http://sms.emefocus.com/sendsms.jsp?user="$uname"&password="$pwd"&mobiles="$mobiil_no"&sms="$msg"&senderid="$sender_id"; $ret = file($url);`- url to send sms to users from user panel and i'm using FILE operation to execute this url as mentioned above.

After executing this when i'm trying to print $ret, its giving me status true and generating message id and sending id.

But its not getting delivered to user....??
When same url i'm executing in browser as `$url = http://sms.emefocus.com/sendsms.jsp?user="$uname"&password="$pwd"&mobiles=98xxxxxx02&sms=Hi..&senderid="$sender_id"`
its getting delivered immediately..??

can anyone help me out..?? Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that this SMS service needs to think a browser and not a bot is executing the request, or there is some "protection" we don't know about. Is there any documentation regarding this particular service ? Is it intended to be used like you're trying to do?

You can try with CURL and see if the behaviour is still the same:

```
<?php
    // create curl resource 
    $ch = curl_init();
    $agent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1)';

    // set url 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "example.com");

    // Fake real browser
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);

    //return the transfer as a string 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

    // $output contains the output string 
    $ret = curl_exec($ch); 

    // close curl resource to free up system resources 
    curl_close($ch);      
?>
```

Does it help?

Comment: till friday above FILE operation code was working, but from yesterday sms are not working...and i'm getting status as TRUE wen m using FILE operation.....

Comment: If you say it was working previously it is quite unlikely that's the problem is PHP related. The fact you receive status true doesn't prove anything in this case. Did you try my code all the same? If you can, I would suggest you try also your code from another server. Your IP may have been banned.

Comment: Sorry Denis even this CURL operation is also not working. I mean i'm not getting any error on executing but sms are not getting delivered....same as FILE operation....!!!! any other possibilities...or ideas....????

Comment: But you're able to make it work if you use the URL directly in your browser right? I assume your computer doesn't share the same IP as the server where the php code is. If my two previous sentences are correct, I suggest you try your code on another server with another IP address.